# Script to make an animation

Tags: python, animation, scripting, bones, pose-mode

I have made an animation in which a sign gesture is being performed. Now i want to to make a script and do the same thing happening in the animation. This armature is performing **quaternion rotation** and i have maintained a dataset file in which all WXYZ values are stored for every bone.

Now i want to change the values frame by frame which i don't understand how to. I know how to change the values and select the bones using script but how to set the value for every frame is the main issue I'm having as i could not find any content related to my problem.

[image]

Comment: Please add more information on data set, and perhaps too,  the script as you have it so far.  Do you want to make a new action from the data set, or is each a pose matching a sign, akin to lip sync?